# How to make an HTA process an high priority

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, process, hta

Is there a way to make an HTA process use more then 3% of the CPU?

We are using a HTA script to scan multiple files. The process is quite long, but my guess is that if we could run the script on high priority it would use more CPU process pourcentage.

I tried running the script with the command  `/high` but that didn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely not the priority that's slowing it down.  It's more likely that it's doing a lot of I/O.

You can set the priority as high as you want, but you can't make it run faster than the physical limitations of the hard drives it's reading from.  The CPU is used only when needed, and if it's waiting for the disk to spin to read the next sector, the processor will work on other tasks.

If it's reading over the network it's also got the issue of the network lag.